# Edit multiple entries of has_many, through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am building a membership system for my rails app and have the following models (without validations and everything else):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :subgroups, through: :memberships
end

class Subgroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

The membership model contains a custom attribute, which holds the membership level.

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subgroup
  belongs_to :user

  scope :guests, -> { where( role: 0 ) }
  scope :users, -> { where( role: 1 ) }
  scope :admins, -> { where( role: 2 ) }
end
```

I want the user to be able to edit all the memberships for one group in one place. There should be three multiple-select fields per group to choose admins, users & guests. For generating forms I use simple_form.

It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vEsx.png), but filled with the user-names (which should be the easy part) and preselected users for each user-level.

Different built-in solutions like `f.association` do not work. I tried this for `:users` (which generates three identical select-fields) and `:memberships`.

So I am seeking help on building the view & controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use scopes in the Subgroup, but not in Membership

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :subgroups, through: :memberships

  scope :guests, -> { includes(:memberships).where('memberships.role' => 0) }
  scope :users,  -> { includes(:memberships).where('memberships.role' => 1) }
  scope :admins, -> { includes(:memberships).where('memberships.role' => 2) }
end
```

or better make new association with lambda wenn you wont to use with simple_form

```
class Subgroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships

  has_many :only_guests, -> { where('memberships.role' => 0).uniq }, through: :memberships, source: :user
  has_many :only_users,  -> { where('memberships.role' => 1).uniq }, through: :memberships, source: :user
  has_many :only_admins, -> { where('memberships.role' => 2).uniq }, through: :memberships, source: :user

end
```

view:

```
<%= f.association :only_users, as: :check_boxes, collection: User.all %>
```

Comment: As i am using simple_form, i tries the second solution with `<%= f.association :only_users %>` in the view. But it returns `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.role: SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "memberships" ON "users"."id" = "memberships"."user_id" WHERE "users"."role" = 1 AND "memberships"."subgroup_id" = ?`

Comment: correct! You must: has_many :only_users,  -> { where('memberships .role' => 1).uniq }, through: :memberships, source: :user

Comment: Then it does not join the tables. Result ist `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: memberships.role: SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "memberships"."role" = 1`
**EDIT**: role is attribute of Membership

Comment: In which table is the attribute "role"?

Comment: I had to use `<%= f.association :only_users, collection: User.all %>` to display the select field. Now it works. Could you add this to your answer?